# Creating and ntegrating payment form using HTML and CSS with Revolut?

Tags: html, css, forms, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I am new to this forum, I am currently doing Scrimba front end developing bootcamp so I am trying to learn. I am running an ecommerce site where I use Stripe as a payment gateway/processor but I don't quite trust Stripe as they have hold my funds for a while several times and I am validating same information to them all the time so it kind of seems very amateurish (I know how big of a company Stripe is) so this is causing me some trouble due to invoicing for the company and I am losing my night sleep over this so I am looking for a solution to try to fix this myself and then I was thinking about revolut. I have a card with revolut and everytime I deposit on the Revolut account it instantly come into that account, with Stripe it takes minimum a week, sometimes 3, if they are in a bad mood.

I was thinking of this process:
Creating a payment form with HTML and CSS code
Integrate somehow that payment with the revolut account.

I have seen some templates on payment forms with HTML and CSS, I haven't yet been able to create it, I am still very new. Is this possible? One of the products are a subscription, where the first price is a 50% offer and the normal subscription runs from the second month.

Anyone that can guide me on how to approach this, if it is do-able?

Thank you for your replies.

Tried googling this solution, tested some of the HTML/CSS forms but since I am a beginner I am kind of lost in all the information around. Still haven't been able to find out with Revolut whether if this is possible or not.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: But I don't have any code.. I can find different templates on various sites (as I mentioned in the thread) but I wasn't referring to a specific code.. Is this forum just for advanced people..?

Answer (score 0):

if you are referring to revolut personal account no it is not possible i had the exactly same issue. But you can prefill some input form its url for example :

https://revolut.me/savvasmira/eur20/commentgoes here/card-payment

https://revolut.me/UR_USER_NAME_PERIONAL_ACCOUNT/CURRENCY_$_AMMOUNT/COMMENT

that's it but keep in mind those input can still be edited via the user.

Incase you have revolut bossiness account then indeed you can integrate there api in your website ( charges apply )[https://developer.revolut.com/]